# Do all Firebase Cloud Messages come with a messageId?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am looking at the code for the fcm messaging library for flutter.

In a RemoteMessage class, the [messageId](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_messaging_platform_interface/latest/firebase_messaging_platform_interface/RemoteMessage/messageId.html) is declared as a nullable type. Does this imply that messages can arrive without a messageId? I was under the impression that all messages come with a messageId...

Answer (score 0):

You can define one when sending a message or othervise there will be an automaticaly generated one. There was once a [bug](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#9.4) that caused that value to be `null`. The message should always have an ID.